# In the simple planar graph G the degree of each vertex is at least 5. Show that in this case G contains at least 12 vertices of degree 5.

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

In the simple planar graph G the degree of each vertex is at least 5. Show that in this case G
contains at least 12 vertices of degree 5.

I tried to solve it in this way:

we know that for simple planar graph to exist this statement ($ e <= 3n - 6 $ ) must hold. n - number of vertices. I found that $ 5n = 2e $ from handshake theorem and then i found that $ e=5n/2 $ . Now I have no idea what to do next. My guess is somehow prove it with help of number of edeges...

Thanks for help!

Comment: To be clear, that's at least $12$ vertices of degree *at least* 5.  Because you could always increase the degree of a vertex by creating another vertex and connecting it to the degree $5$ vertex with a new edge.

Comment: Actually, it's at least 12 vertices of degree exactly 5. This is a planar graph; we can't just add edges freely, and each new vertex added must have degree at least 5 by the problem's rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're trying to count how many vertices there are of a particular degree - so how about naming the numbers of vertices of each degree. Let $n_5$ be the number of vertices of degree $5$, $n_6$ be the number of vertices of degree $6$, and so on. What do the vertex and edge counts look like in terms of these?

Comment: I don't have any guesses

Comment: So simple! It may be worth pointing out that $12$ is possible. Stereographically project an icosahedron to a plane.

Answer (score 1):

Since the minimum degree is at least 5, n=6 , and we know that for a simple planar graph with$n \geq 3$, $m \leq 3n-6$. Since minimum degree is 5. $m \geq  \frac{5n}{2}$. 
 So ,  $ 5n/2\leq 3n-6$
$ \Rightarrow5n \leq 6n-12 $
which gives $ n \geq 12$

Comment: So there are at least 12 vertices. But the goal is to show that there are at least 12 vertices of degree **exactly** five.